# CircleCI: MySQL starts on its own even after stopping the process

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, circleci

I am having some trouble with default MySQL installation on CircleCI. In 'post' section of 'machine', I stop mysql using, "- sudo service mysql stop". The reason behind doing so is that I want to use docker mysql container on port 3306. My "docker-compose up" takes some time to finish and sometimes before the docker mysql container starts, the mysql process starts again for no reason obvious to me. I have been tracking this issue using the following command.

```
while true; do sudo netstat -nlp | grep :3306; sleep 2; done
```

I have a build that ran fine with docker being able to register port 3306, and also a build in which mysqld started again even after stopping giving me the following error on docker-compose up.

```
ERROR: for dbm01  Cannot start service dbm01: failed to create endpoint minimum_dbm01_1 on network minimum_default: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Both the builds are of same commit so there is no difference in code. What might be the issue?